# Cannot add foreign key constraint using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

Trying to create a todo list with sequelize but I always hava this error:
"Cannot add foreign key constraint using Sequelize" Even looking for some clues in StackOverflow, somone can help?

ToDo Migration

```
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Todos', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      status_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Statuses',
          key: 'id',
        },
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Todos');
  },
};
```

Status migration

```
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Statuses', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Statuses');
  },
};

Relationship in models
```

```
// Status model
  Status.associate = (models) => {
    Status.belongsTo(models.Todo, { foreignKey: 'status_id', as: 'todo' });
  };

// Todo model
  Todo.associate = (models) => {
    Todo.hasMany(models.Status, { foreignKey: 'status_id', as: 'statuses' });
  };
```

If someone have any idea I'm really appreciate! Thanks

Comment: What is the actual order of these migrations?

Answer (score 0):

When the "Todos" table has the "status_id",

it must "belong to" the "Statuses" table.

Or you should save the "todo_id" in the "Statuses" table.

```
  // Status model
  Status.associate = (models) => {
    Status.hasMany(models.Todo, { foreignKey: 'status_id', as: 'todos' });
  };

  // Todo model
  Todo.associate = (models) => {
    Todo.belongsTo(models.Status, { foreignKey: 'status_id', as: 'status' });
  };
```